# Sequencer / Linking and updating strips

Tags: edit-mode, video-sequence-editor

I'm trying to make a dynamic editing of several strips, but 'im facing two problems to make it work :

1 - I put all my strips (blue ones) end to end. I would like to be able to modify the file of each strip, the content and even its time (longer for example), and that those modifications are effective in my editing file into the sequencer.

In my video editing, every strip (or shot) contains a specific video file.
This video file is a playblast from another blender file (I have one .blend for each shot, and so one playblast.mov for each shot, and I update the same .mov file if I have to add modification), but I sometimes need to extend the duration of some shots. So their playblasts are longer, and I would like them to update automatically into the video editing (another blender file).
But for the moment, they keep their initial duration (so they're cut), instead of automatically extend and push other strips.
The only solution I'm seeing for the moment, is to manually extend each shot related to a playblast with a new duration.

2 - I also would like to link sound and text to each strip, like in Premiere. For example, I always have shot 01, shot 02 and shot 03 : I want to link the sound of shot 01 with its video strip, so if I modify or move the one or the other, the other is also modified and follows.

Here is an example (text in purple, video in blue and sound in green)

[image: example of linked strips]

If you don't know any solution directly into blender, maybe addons exist to do this kind of operations ?

Thanks in advance,

Okikoulpa

Comment: i am pretty sure Batfinger can make you a script for this in 10 mins ;)

Comment: Possibly, tho would recommend searching on the answers of [@tintotin](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/37272/tintwotin)  or @3pointedit  who specialize in creating scripts / addons for the VSE

Comment: 1. Press Alt while transforming strip(s) and the following strips will reposition themselves accordingly. Blender Alpha 3.0 have an Insert/expand mode to do this on all transforms without pressing alt.
2. Use the VSEQF add-on for link/parent functionality: https://github.com/snuq/VSEQF

Comment: --Thank you everyone.

@tintwotin , I have not tested the addon yet, but I think it's exactly what I waslooking for.
For my first question (1), pressing "alt" may be the solution for some cases, but it is not exactly what I'm looking for. I've updated my question with more precisions.

Comment: Does anyone have an idea to update strips ?